# Derivation of the Latin Word "fores"

Tags: proto-indo-european, linguistics

I was reading up on Grimm's law and an example that I saw of voiced aspirated stops becoming voiced stops (dh -> d specifiaclly) was that of the word "dhwer" (door) becoming the word "fores" in latin. I just don't understand how dh becoming a d explains how dhwer became fores?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site! Where did you read this?

Comment: Thank you! I read this in a book about Old English that contained a section about Grimm's law.

Comment: Grimm's law is a sound law in Germanic, it does not apply to Latin.

Answer (score 2):

The Proto-Indo-European sound usually reconstructed as **dʰ* regularly becomes *f* at the beginning of a word in Latin, like **dʰh₁-k-* becoming *faciō*.

On its own, the Latin evidence doesn't tell us much about what the Proto-Indo-European sound would have been. But Greek has a *th* in this root, and Sanskrit a *dh*, which is why we reconstruct **dʰ*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is very much appreciated. I just couldn't work out where the f came from.

Comment: Any comment on the mechanism of f < dh?